# How to capture screen in android when application is running in background?

Tags: android

I was using this code to capture screen but it captures only activity not the screen when application runs in background.

```
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = MyView.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

can any one proposed the capture screen code which can capture what ever is in screen.

Comment: You need root permission if you want to take screenshot outside of your app.

Comment: can you give me any helping material

Comment: You can take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/source/browse/#hg%2Fdemo%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Comment: do you have any example code snip i am working on this since last couple of month but its not being solved.

Comment: @Nauman Khalid did u got any example code snipet on this concept